# Row wise Count for multiple columns

Tags: r

Hi I am trying to count of values for multiple columns from a data frame

```
date = c('2020-01-01','2020-01-02','2020-01-03','2020-01-04')
a= c(1,NA,1,NA)
b= c(1,0,1,NA)
c = c(NA,NA,0,NA)
df = data.frame(date,a,b,c)
```

I tried with the below code to count number of values from all 3 columns

```
df$tot_cnt =  rowSums(df[,c('a','b','c')], na.rm=TRUE)
```

I am looking for output that will be like

```
tot_cnt = c(2,1,3,NA)
df = data.frame(date,a,b,c,tot_cnt)
```

Comment: you mean `rowSums(!is.na(df[-1]))` ?

Comment: Did any of the below answer worked for you? Please consider to accept any one of the answer so that question can be marked as solved.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `rowSums()`. It's better to use `apply()` over the rows by specifying `1` as the margin. Here is the code that should do what you asked:

```
date = c('2020-01-01','2020-01-02','2020-01-03','2020-01-04')
a= c(1,NA,1,NA)
b= c(1,0,1,NA)
c = c(NA,NA,0,NA)
df = data.frame(date,a,b,c)

counts = apply(df[ , 2:4], 1, function(x) sum(!is.na(x)) )
counts[ which( counts == 0 )] = NA_integer_
df$tot_cnt = counts
> df
        date  a  b  c tot_cnt
1 2020-01-01  1  1 NA       2
2 2020-01-02 NA  0 NA       1
3 2020-01-03  1  1  0       3
4 2020-01-04 NA NA NA      NA
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `rowSums` to count non-NA values in each row.

```
df$tot_cnt <- rowSums(!is.na(df[-1]))
df$tot_cnt
#[1] 2 1 3 0
```

If you want to replace 0 with `NA`, you could do :

```
df$total_cnt[df$total_cnt == 0] <- NA
```